# JSON.Stringify data including boolean values

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

What I'm trying to do is to pass JSON object to a WebAPI ajax call and mapped to a strongly typed object on the server side. String values are being posted perfectly however when it comes to boolean values, they are not being passed at all. Below is my code:

```
 var gsGasolineField = $('.gsGasoline').val();
 blData = { Gasoline: gsGasolineField  };

 var json = JSON.stringify(blData);
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: json,
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         statusCode: {
                      201 /*Created"*/: function (data) {
                            $("#BusinessLayerDialog").dialog("close");
                            ClearForm("#BusinessLayerForm");
                        },
                        400: /*Bad request - validation error*/ function (data) {
                            $("#BusinessLayerForm").validate().form();

                        },
                        500: function (data) {
                            alert('err');
                        }
                    },
         beforeSend: setHeader
                });
```

Gasoline property is of type boolean on the server side.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned above, Gasoline is boolean and being MVC my HTML markup is as follows

```
<div style="float: left">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.GasStation.Gasoline, new { @class = "gsGasoline" })</div>
```

So I'm just taking the values of this checkbox and passing it to the JSON object

**EDIT**

Also tried to to send it true directly

```
blData = { Gasoline: true  };
```

Still false server side!

Comment: What type of field is gsGasoline

Comment: Could you please also include the code for the Action on your controller, the C# class that you try to map to, and the HTML markup for .gsGasoline?

Comment: If gsGasolineField is a checkbox, that will return "on" or "off", not a boolean. Try `(gsGasolineField === 'on' ? true : false)` or just `(gsGasolineField === 'on')`

Comment: I think `jQuery.val()` always returns a string, not a boolean.

Comment: @Barmar - It does, it's always a string, and stringifying it most certainly makes it a string, so why check for a boolean on the serverside ?

Comment: I was wrong, checkboxes don't seem to work like that; instead you should be using `$('.gsGasoline').is(':checked')`

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`? This will *prevent* the parameters from being sent correctly!

Comment: The properties are being send correctly except for boolean values.

Comment: Please note that I'm basing my assumption on the following MSDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify Note the following : "Boolean, Number, and String objects are converted to the corresponding primitive values during stringification, in accord with the traditional conversion semantics."

Comment: @ancdev: Lose the `stringify` and use Kiyura's `:checked` version for the value. I think that you are simply misusing these "building blocks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be due to the inheritance aspect of my server side architecture. All properties in the parent class are being deserialized correctly and everything in the child class remains untouched. Nothing was related to the type passed to the JSON.Stringify function.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('.gsGasoline').val()` to `$('.gsGasoline').is(':checked')`